# Concatenate certain arrays elements into a int in Arduino

Tags: concatenation

I have an array of 7 elements, wich contains some values combinations..

for example, I need to transform from 2nd to 4th into a 234 int.

char myarray[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7'};

int i = atoi(myarray);

printf("%d\n", i);

This way, it returns the int, but all array values...1234567

Comment: Just a correction.. the myarray is myarray[7] size..(not 5)

Comment: Can you destroy other values in the array?  If so: ``myarray[4] = '\0'; i=atoi(myarray+1);``

Comment: actually, no I can't.. At this time, need to retrieve the 2nd, 3rd and 4th only, and preserve all other items..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
int atoisub(char *s, int start, int end)
{
    int rv = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        rv = rv * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Call as `atoisub(myarray, 1, 4)`.  There's no error checking for non-digit characters or invalid parameters.

Comment: hi. Works perfect! I'm just having some dificult to understand about why this -'0' at the end.. But thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: The character '0' does not have the numeric value 0 - in fact, its value is 48 in the ASCII character set.  To convert character strings to numbers, we need to subtract 48 from each character - which I chose to express in the form ``'0'`` to hopefully make it clearer why that value is being used.  (This also makes the code work right on non-ASCII character sets, not that anybody uses such things anymore.)

Comment: I checked the ASCII table and understood why of the '0' now.. Thank you so much!